mirroring in blockchain
Can anyone verify if below sentence in "" can be true as I'm asked to hold money in my hot wallet in order to allow mirror process (https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/6.x?topic=shipping-mirror-transaction-transformer-program) to flow and to be able to withdraw money? or it is a scam?
"As soon as the exact amount you need to have on your hot wallet account, the system will start the mirror transaction through the Blockchain - to your Cold Wallet, and from there you will have to move it yourself into your hot wallet account. When it arrives to the hot wallet you'll need to sell the Bitcoins for Euros and the Euros you will be able to make a bank transfer to your bank" - sentence from communication with Remittance Officer.

This question is similar to: I got scammed or suspect scam on Ethereum or Uniswap. What to do?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
